# Filtering RadGrid by ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik, radgrid

My problem is that when I try to click the combobox within my Radgrid, it doesn't do anything.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="TestReleaseInformationSource" ShowStatusBar="true"
            OnItemCommand="RadGridItemCommand" OnPreRender="RadGrid_PreRender" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false"
            AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="true">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="PrimaryKey">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowFiltering="true" UniqueName="TeacherLastName" DataField="TeacherLastName" HeaderText="Last Name">
                        <FilterTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="radComboBoxLastName" DataSourceID="TeacherLastNameDDL" DataTextField="TeacherLastName" DataValueField="TeacherLastName"
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.GetColumn("TeacherLastName").CurrentFilterValue %>'
                                runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="TeacherLastNameChanged">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All" Selected="true" />
                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                            <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function TeacherLastNameChanged(sender, args)
                                    {
                                        var tableView = $find("<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.ClientID %>");
                                        tableView.filter("TeacherLastName", args.get_item().get_value(), "EqualTo");
                                    }
                                </script>
                            </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
                        </FilterTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

On prerender of the grid

```
    protected void RadGrid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadGrid.EditItems.Count > 0)
        {
            GridNestedViewItem item = (GridNestedViewItem)RadGrid.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.NestedView)[Convert.ToInt32(RadGrid.EditIndexes[0])];
            item.Visible = false;
        }

        if (RadGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression != string.Empty)
        {
            RefreshCombos();
        }
    }

    protected void RefreshCombos()
    {
        TestReleaseInformationSource.SelectCommand = TestReleaseInformationSource.SelectCommand + " WHERE " + RadGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression.ToString();

        RadGrid.MasterTableView.Rebind();
    }
```

I've stared at this for hours and can not figure out what the problem is. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Will post more code if necessary.

A solution I have found is to set the RenderMode property of the combobox to native. I would still like a different workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the JS functions unique: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/details/using-dynamic-unique-names-for-javascript-functions
I think that all of them override each other so only the last one is active so only that executes. Also, look for JS errors.

Also, try invoking the filtering from the client as shown here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-client-side-binding-adding-sort-filter-expressions.html.
The masterTableView object is best obtained via the get_masterTableView() method of the main grid object.